# Change the calenderextender default date

Tags: c#, asp.net, datepicker

I have FROM DATE and TO DATE in a web form both are using the ajax calenderextender. When users select the FROM DATE and I want to default the TO DATE calenderextender date to FROM DATE +2 days. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript to set the `SelectedDate` property of "To Date" Calendar in `OnClientShowing` event. This is how you can do this:

in markup:

```
<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="toDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDate" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" OnClientShowing="setDefaultDate" />
```

in javascript:

```
function setDefaultDate(sender,args)
{
    if(sender._textbox.get_element().value == "")
    {
        var selectedDate = new Date(); //here i am using current date but you can get the selected date of From Calendar control and add +2 days
        sender._selectedDate = selectedDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried the following code, but I am getting the following error Uncaught TypeError: Object  has no method 'getFullYear' function setDefaultDate(sender,args) 
        {     
            if(sender._textbox.get_element().value == "")     
            {
                var selectedDate = $('#<%=txtHotelCheckOutDate.ClientID %>').val();
                sender._selectedDate = selectedDate;
            } 
        }

Comment: i guess there is a problem with my given code itself, try changing sender._selectedDate to sender.set_selectedDate(selectedDate) or sender.set_selectedDate($find('<%= txtHotelCheckOutDate.ClientID %>').get_selectedDate())

Comment: Actually your code is working fine. I changed the var selectedDate = new Date($('#<%=txtHotelCheckOutDate.ClientID %>').val()); and it is working now. Thanks for your help